# How to represent an object with jQuery and Bootstrap properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently writing a small page which will gather holidays (objects I will get from an **AJAX** query). I through it would be a great opportunity to write **jQuery** code to "render" HTML code, since, in the past, I only generated entities from **PHP**. My idea is first to get every **holidays** from a **database** and to create **Bootstrap panels** for each of them, and then to constantly search for other holidays which would have been inserted since the previous database retrieving. I am at the step to write the **jQuery** code to "render" objects I will get from the **database**.

The issue I am working on right now, since I begin with jQuery, is how to organize my code well - **how to properly generate these panels** - and avoid writing too much (and ugly) code. As you may see, I repeat myself a lot on the jQuery section.

What you should know is that I test this code with a little **jQuery object** for an holiday, which is (at the moment), represented by:

```
var $holiday = {
    'title': 'Foobar',
    'date': '2016-12-26',
};
```

In future, I will get a list of objects like the `$holiday` above and loop the list to "render" **Bootstrap panels**.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Holidays</title>
        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="container" id="content"></div>
        </main>
        <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // jQuery code below
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my jQuery code I would like to minimize:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    appendHolidays();
});

function appendHolidays()
{
    var $title = renderTitle('Holidays');
    var $holidays = renderHolidays();
    var $contentContainer = $('#content');

    $contentContainer.append($title);
    $contentContainer.append($holidays);
}

function renderTitle($title)
{
    var $titleTag = $('<h1 />')
        .text($title);
    var $titleContainer = $('<div />')
        .addClass('page-header')
        .append($titleTag);

    return $titleContainer;
}

function renderHolidayId($id)
{
    var $holidayId = $('<span />')
        .attr('hidden', 'hidden')
        .addClass('holiday-id')
        .text($id)

    return $holidayId;
}

function renderHolidayTitle($title)
{
    var $holidayTitle = $('<span />')
        .addClass('holiday-title')
        .text($title)

    return $holidayTitle;
}

function renderHolidayDate($date)
{
    var $holidayDate = $('<span />')
        .addClass('holiday-date')
        .text($date);

    return $holidayDate;
}

function renderHolidayPanelBody($holiday)
{
    var $holidayId = renderHolidayId($holiday.id);
    var $holidayTitle = renderHolidayTitle($holiday.title);
    var $holidayDate = renderHolidayDate($holiday.date);
    var $panelBody = $('<div />')
        .addClass('panel-body');

    $panelBody.append($holidayId);
    $panelBody.append($holidayTitle);
    $panelBody.append($holidayDate);

    return $panelBody;
}

function renderHolidayPanel($holiday)
{
    var $panelBody = renderHolidayPanelBody($holiday);
    var $panel = $('<div />')
        .addClass('panel')
        .addClass('panel-default')
        .append($panelBody);

    return $panel;
}

function renderHolidayCol($holiday)
{
    var $panel = renderHolidayPanel($holiday);
    var $col = $('<div />')
        .addClass('col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6')
        .append($panel);

    return $col;
}

function renderHolidays()
{
    var $holiday = {
        'title': 'Foobar',
        'date': '2016-12-26',
    };
    var $row = $('<div />')
        .addClass('row')
    var $col = renderHolidayCol($holiday);

    $row.append($col.clone(true));
    $row.append($col.clone(true));
    $row.append($col.clone(true));
    $row.append($col.clone(true));
    $row.append($col.clone(true));
    $row.append($col.clone(true));
    $row.append($col.clone(true));

    return ($row);
}
```

I think there is a better way to render every little HTML part than this, but I'm not able to think out of the box and maybe I am missing something important there. How you would have written this code in a minimal way?

I hope this question will also help other user to keep a bit organized and improve code quality-readibility

Comment: I'd say this will also be a good opportunity to look into a templating system like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com). Although, jquery provides ways to dynamically create HTML contents, and it is fine to use them for creating elements for very small projects. But as your project grows and the number of different types of elements you want create increases, it becomes complex and unwieldy. A templating system will make your life easy in this case.

Comment: won't your calls to `$('<div />')` and `$('<span />')` always return every div on your page?

Comment: Are you open to a tool like knockoutJS or ReactJS?

Comment: I have a look at every technology people recommend. It is very interesting to figure out how many technology could help to solve my issue. I tried ReactJS but found it was too **strict**, because it forces you to be very careful about when you are opening and closing HTML tags and how you describe them

Comment: @FrazerKirkman That is how you create new Dom elements with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least don't enforce all the holidays to be exactly the same like this.

And loop the given holidays in stead of adding a line for each one in the renderHolidays.

Also look into Angular, HandleBars, Mustache, Dust etc.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  appendHolidays();
});

function appendHolidays() {
  var $title = renderTitle('Holidays');
  var holidays = [{
    'title': 'Foobar1',
    'date': '2016-12-26',
  }, {
    'title': 'Foobar2',
    'date': '2016-12-26',
  }, {
    'title': 'Foobar3',
    'date': '2016-12-26',
  }];
  var $holidays = renderHolidays(holidays);
  var $contentContainer = $('#content');

  $contentContainer.append($title);
  $contentContainer.append($holidays);
}

function renderTitle($title) {
  var $titleTag = $('<h1 />')
    .text($title);
  var $titleContainer = $('<div />')
    .addClass('page-header')
    .append($titleTag);

  return $titleContainer;
}

function renderHolidayId($id) {
  var $holidayId = $('<span />')
    .attr('hidden', 'hidden')
    .addClass('holiday-id')
    .text($id)

  return $holidayId;
}

function renderHolidayTitle($title) {
  var $holidayTitle = $('<span />')
    .addClass('holiday-title')
    .text($title)

  return $holidayTitle;
}

function renderHolidayDate($date) {
  var $holidayDate = $('<span />')
    .addClass('holiday-date')
    .text($date);

  return $holidayDate;
}

function renderHolidayPanelBody($holiday) {
  var $holidayId = renderHolidayId($holiday.id);
  var $holidayTitle = renderHolidayTitle($holiday.title);
  var $holidayDate = renderHolidayDate($holiday.date);
  var $panelBody = $('<div />')
    .addClass('panel-body');

  $panelBody.append($holidayId);
  $panelBody.append($holidayTitle);
  $panelBody.append($holidayDate);

  return $panelBody;
}

function renderHolidayPanel($holiday) {
  var $panelBody = renderHolidayPanelBody($holiday);
  var $panel = $('<div />')
    .addClass('panel')
    .addClass('panel-default')
    .append($panelBody);

  return $panel;
}

function renderHolidayCol($holiday) {
  var $panel = renderHolidayPanel($holiday);
  var $col = $('<div />')
    .addClass('col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6')
    .append($panel);

  return $col;
}
 
function renderHolidays(holidays) {
  var $row = $('<div />')
    .addClass('row');
  for (var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
    $row.append(renderHolidayCol(holidays[i]));
  }
  return ($row);
}
```

```css
.holiday-title {
  font-weight:bold;
  }
.holiday-date{
  float:right;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<main>
  <div class="container" id="content"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Enforcing `$holiday` "holidays" to be the same is only for testing purpose of course!